# Add tag "reference-letter" as a synonym for "recommendation-letter"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can someone please create the tag [reference-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-letter) as a synonym for [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter)?  The tag-info excerpt at [recommendation-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter) begins:

> Questions on recommendation or reference letters ...

so it's clear that *reference letter* is an accepted idiom for the same concept.  But users who begin to type *reference* when entering a tag into a new question are tempted to choose [references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references), which redirects to [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations), and is usually not what was intended.

(A recent example is this question [Can I ask a non-academic for an academic letter of recommendation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/125941/23642), which was [originally tagged](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/125941/1) [citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added the synonym. Enjoy!